# How to write regular expressions in CSS

Tags: css, regex, css-selectors

How do I use regular expressions in CSS?  I found a tutorial [here](http://webhole.net/2010/01/14/css-regular-expressions/) for matching static strings in CSS, but I haven't been able to find one for using regular expressions to match multiple strings in CSS. (I found one [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/regex-matching-attribute-selectors/), but I couldn't get it to work.  I also looked at the [W3C documentation on using regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar), but I couldn't make sense of the document.)

I'm want to match a series of `<DIV>` tags whose ids start at `s1` and increase by one (ie. `#s1 #s2 #s3`...).

I know that `div[id^=s]`, `div[id^='s']`, and `div[id^='s']` each perform the match as I intend it in my CSS.  However, each of those also match an id of `#section`, which I don't want to happen.  I believe that `"/^s([0-9])+$/"` is the equivalent PHP string--I'm just looking for it in CSS version.

Comment: Your link about regular expressions in CSS isn't a tutorial; it's a blog entry that starts with "They don’t exist, but wouldn’t that be so cool?"; your W3C documentation link isn't about regular expressions, it's about the CSS grammar in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to match elements with a regular expression, [even in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). Your best option is probably to simply use a class for your `div`s.

```
<style>
.s-div {
    // stuff specific to each div
}
</style>

<div id="s1" class="s-div"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="s2" class="s-div"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="s3" class="s-div"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="s4" class="s-div"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="s5" class="s-div"><!-- stuff --></div>
```

Also remember that you can separate multiple class names by a space inside a `class` attribute.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

Comment: I'm familiar with using classes, but I'll stick with my long selector string of `#s1, #s2, #s3, #s4...` in my CSS.  It's less redundant than using both ids and classes in my HTML.

Comment: @Alien, if your `div`s with ids have a common ancestor, maybe `#ancestor-id > div[id^='s']` could be a functional rule too.

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:
    /* page scrape the DIV s# id's and generate the style selector */
    re=/<div\b[^>]*\b(id=(('|")?)s[0-9]+\2)(\b[^>]*)?>/ig;
    alert(
        document . body . innerHTML .
            match(re) . join("") .
                replace(re,"div[$1], ") + "{ styling details here }" );

    alert(
       ("test with <div id=s2 aadf><DIV ID=123> <DIV adf=asf as><Div id='s45'>" +
              "<div id=s2a ><DIV ID=s23 > <DIV asdf=as id=S9 ><Div id='x45' >") .
            match(re) . join("") .
                replace(re,"div[$1], ") + "{ styling details here }"
        );
```

The test yields

```
div[id=s2], div[id='s45'], div[ID=s23], div[id=S9], { styling details here }
```

Note the dangling `,` and the case preserved `S9`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't use the solution posted by @zneak, you could do that editing the labels with javascript, but i'll advice you: It's a hell of work.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS will select `#s0, #s1, ... , #s9` and not `#section`, though a browser must implement the CCS3 negation `:not()`.
The final selection is equivalent to:

```
/^s[0-9]?.*[0-9]$/
```

which says that each id must start with `s` and a number and end with a number like:

```
s6, s42, s123, s5xgh7, ...
```

The `:not()` line vacuously excludes those ID's that do not start properly using an empty style `{}`.

```
<style>
div:not([id^=s0]):not([id^=s1]):not([id^=s2]):not ... :not([id^=s9]) {}
div[id^=s][id$=0], div[id^=s][id$=1], div[id^=s][id$=2], ... div[id^=s][id$=9] { ... }
</style>
```

CSS3 does not use regular expressions to define selectors BUT ...
[CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-conditional/#url-regexp)
defines a very specific function, `regexp(<`*`string`*`>)`, that parses a URL with a regular expression when creating an *`@document`* rule.

Comment: The reference given in the question [10. The grammar of Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar) defines the syntax used to express a selector. The syntax of that grammar itself IS not the same as a selector's! The `LL(1)` and `LL(2)` in the article and `RE` (regular expressions) are all formal definitions for grammars. In particular, `LL(1)` and `LL(2)` are not `RE` (as opposed to Recursively Enumerable but that's another story!). NB. There is NO reference in that article to `'regular expression'`.

Comment: There are 3 grammars relevant to that article (not including the English)   
1 - the grammar describing a selector's grammar `selectors_group
  : selector [ COMMA S* selector ]*
  ;`   
2 - the selector's grammar `div[id^=s][id$=9]` (which is `LL`)
and 3- the HTML grammar that the selector picks `<DIV ID=s1>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
/* eliminate the alphabet except s - NB some funny characters may be left */
/* HTML id's are case-sensitive - upper case may need exclusion & inclusion */
div[id*=a], div[id*=b], div[id*=c], ..., div[id*=q], div[id*=r] {}
div[id*=t], div[id*=u], div[id*=v], div[id*=w], div[id*=x], div[id*=y], div[id*=z] {}
div[id*='_'], div[id*='-'], div[id*='%'], div[id*='#'] {}

/* s can not be embedded */
div[id*=0s], div[id*=1s], div[id*=2s], ..., div[id*=9s] {}

/* s will be followed by a string of numerals - maybe a funny char or two */
div[id^=s0], div[id^=s1], div[id^=s2], ... div[id^=s9] { ... }
</style>
```